# Trigger executed after batch

Tags: trigger, batch

I have a scenario where I insert orderItem records using a batch class.
I have an after insert trigger on OrderItem that calls a batch to update on other object.

I'm getting an error

> "System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a
>   batch start, batch ..."

when after insert trigger fires.

It doesnt give me an error when i put this in trigger code,

```
if(trigger.new !=null && trigger.new.size() > 0 &&!system.isFuture() && !system.isbatch()){
        Database.executeBatch(new UpdateSubProductsBatch(trigger.new),500);
    }
```

but doesn't execute the batch from trigger.

If I take off the `!system.isbatch()` from if conditions, its gives me the above error.

Can you please help me in understanding the situation and how to deal with it.

I am using the batch after the after insert trigger, because i have to update bulk records.

Comment: why you need batch can't you used future method?

Comment: Will I not face the same error "System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch ...", when i use future, i mean execute a future method from after insert trigger?

Comment: How you are inserting `orderItem` ? from batch i think?

Comment: Ya its from batch

Comment: Anurag... then dont execute `UpdateSubProductsBatch` batch from trigger.. instead when your first batch completed, call `UpdateSubProductsBatch`  method from first batch's finish method.

Comment: Ya,i'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your question**

Dont execute `UpdateSubProductsBatch` batch from trigger..

instead when your first batch process completed, call `UpdateSubProductsBatch` method from first batch's `finish method`

---

You are trying to execute batch from inside a batch process that's the reason you are getting Error

> System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a
>   batch start, batch .

---

### Updates

Use `Database.Stateful` to collect all Account.. And check in finish method..

```
global class SummarizeAccountTotal implements 
    Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{


   private List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();


   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ID from Account]);
   }

   global void execute(
                Database.BatchableContext BC, 
                List<sObject> scope){
      for(Account acc : scope){
         lstAccount.add(acc);
      }
   }

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       system.debug('-----lstAccount-----'+lstAccount);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ratan, how do I pass a list of records that are inserted in execute method to finish, i need to pass them for the second batch.

Comment: @AnuragA, You can use database.stateful or if you have too much data to pass then you can write the data to a custom object and reference that in the next batch. There are various options.

Comment: @AnuragA yes use database.stateful

Comment: @AnuragA check my updated ans. you can follow like that and don't forgot to implement  `database.stateful`